# Is it possible for a Demon to use a breathing style technique?

Tags: demon-slayer

I am just wondering since it doesn't have any requirements pertaining on using breathing style techniques you just only need to learn how to use it with proper training, Does it mean it is possible for a demon to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes but I might be wrong in some details;

> Kokushibo is a member of the Twelve Demon Moons, holding the position of Upper Moon One. In his Human life, he was a demon slayer who trained him by a Breath of Wind user. And now as a Demon with an adept Demon Slayer Breath style(Breath of the Moon). [image]

Comment: Your answer is right but You should put a label of SPOILER ALERT. :)

Comment: I don't think he used the Breath of Wind.

Answer (score 2):

Another demon who uses a breath style is,

> Kaigaku "Kaigaku (獪かい岳がく Kaigaku?) was a Demon Slayer in the Demon Slaying Corps, and Zenitsu Agatsuma's senior disciple under Jigoro Kuwajima. However, he became a demon to save his own life and became Upper Moon Six of the Twelve Demon Moons, replacing Daki and Gyutaro. " [Kaigaku](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Kaigaku) .

He uses thunder breath style.